# Why does "New System.Windows.Forms.Button" take more time in my .net application

Tags: .net, winforms

Right now, I am facing a very weird problem. We've got a .net solution. It's a comparatively big solution which contains a lots of projects. In one project which is responsible for GUI, we create a lots of winforms(labels, buttons, listbox, etc.) with VB.net before our client app gets started. Recently, customers asked us why our Client app takes more time to be initialized.

When I dig into our code, I found just one piece of "Me.BtnMenu = New System.Windows.Forms.Button" clause takes about 10ms to be completed. Actually, we have hundreds of winforms to be constructed before Client GUI is initialized. Recently, We migrate our solution from vs2008 into vs2010. By comparison, in the vs2008 version, the cost of "New System.Windows.Forms.Button" is about 0~1ms, but in the vs2010 version, the cost of "New System.Windows.Forms.Button" is about 10~20ms, which eventually, delay the initialization of GUI. More interesting, other controls like GroupBox, Panel, RadioButton, etc. do not cost so many time in both version, only button deos.

Does any one has any idea on this ? It baffles me for weeks, and I still cannot get it.

Comment: Can you try measuring how much time it takes to create a button in an isolated project/solution? Just to be sure if it is something else in your project or machine maybe causing this delay.

Comment: Thanks for your response and advise. It's getting more interesting, When I isolated one form from our project and import this form into a new solution, The problem persists and even worse. It takes me about 500ms to initialize all this controls while in my original project/solution, it takes about 200ms.

It seems that it has nothing to do with the project/solution's settings such as optimization enabled.

Comment: 10-20 msec is one of those familiar numbers.  It is how accurate you can measure elapsed time on Windows.  Doesn't have anything to do with code.  Use a *real profiler*.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be the parent of the Button object that is causing this issues. Sometimes if the Panel/Form is recalculating/Redrawing the layout when a new Control is added to its collection , a simple operation like adding a simple button would take more time. If you are using a custom panel or a layout that is calculated when controls are added/removed, trying adding the form elements directly to the form.

Also check if the parent form/panel has a method that would pause the redrawing of the form or stop the layout calculations, e.g. BeingUpdate/EndUpdate (or similar ones).